# Artem GoogleMap vs Subgurim GoogleMaps

Tags: asp.net, .net, google-maps, controls, subgurim-maps

I know that many of you don't like these "vs" topics/questions but I am planning to develop new project which will use Google Maps API and I am not sure which of these 2 controls(wrappers) to use.

1st GoogleMap Control by Velio Ivanov(Artem)

http://googlemap.artembg.com/

http://googlemap.codeplex.com/

2nd GoogleMaps by Subgurim.net

http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/

Both controls looks to be better choice than the rest, but I am not sure which actually is the best.
I am looking for quite easy, lightweight and at the same time powerful and well documented control.

Has anyone ever used both of them? Did you have any problems with either? Did you have hard nut to crack as I have?

I will be very grateful for any comparison, advantages, disadvantages, problems etc. which may help me to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have been using the Artem Map Control for some time and it has been very easy to work with.  Additionally, it IS open source and the Subgurim control is NOT.  If you use the Subgurim control in free mode you are exposing your program to ad's as their page says:

*- Only for non commercial applications. Fully functional. No
   limitations. With **messages** and HTML code comments from
   GoogleMaps.Subgurim.NET.*

I am upgrading to v6 the Artem Map Control after I write this